# Unable to test the value of a number in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send a number from a user to an external javascript file  ie .js and determine if it is less than or greater than another number

```js
function processFormData() {
  var name_element = document.getElementById('txt_name');
  var x = name_element;
  var x = Number(+x); 
  if (x > 10) {
   alert("large number");
  } else {
   alert ("small number");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="demo2.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="name">Your Name: </label>
  <input type="number" name="name" id="txt_name">
</p>
</label>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" 
       onclick="processFormData();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts to convert the text field **itself** into a number, rather than the `value` of the text field.

**NOTES**:

- There's no need to set a variable up for the text field and then another to the first.
- You have an extra `</label>` tag in your code.
- The `for` attribute of a `label` must point to the `id` of some form
  field, not the `name` attribute value.
- Don't give elements a `name` or an `id` of `name` as this often
  causes problems with the Global `name` property of the `window`
  object.

```js
function processFormData() {
  var name_element = document.getElementById('txt_name');
  // Convert the value of the element by prepending + to it
  var x = +name_element.value; 
  if (x > 10) {
   alert("large number");
  } else {
   alert ("small number");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="demo2.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="txt_name">Your Name: </label>
  <input type="number" name="txt_name" id="txt_name">
</p>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="processFormData();">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some pointless things here, first of all, why do you create two variables that points to the same object?

The second line is totally unnecessary. You are good to go with name_element.

```
var name_element = document.getElementById('txt_name');
var x = name_element;
```

And the solution to your problem is, you are trying to convert a DOM element to the number. Instead you should access to textContent first.

```
var numericalValue = Number(name_element.textContent);
// If you are expecting that input from a input box
// then you need to use name_element.value
if (x > 10) {
    alert("large number");
  } else {
    alert ("small number");
  }
```

Comment: Text fields (or any form element for that matter) don't have any `.textContent`, they have a `value`.